# Zero map is not angle preserving. We can prove this or this is convention?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, the angle between two **non-zero** vectors $x,y$ is defined by 
$$\cos^{-1}\frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\|x\|.\|y\|}.$$
A linear map $T:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is said to be angle preserving if for non-zero vectors $x,y$, angle between $x,y$ is equal to angle between $Tx$ and $Ty$.

I was trying to check whether zero map is angle preserving? If not, how to prove? If the answer depends on some convention, what should be the convention?

Unfortunately, some books on Linear algebra do not define *angle*; and those books which define it, do not consider this extreme case (of zero map- is it angle preserving) at least in exercises or in remarks.

Comment: Angle is only defined for nonzero vectors.  It sounds like in order for the question to make sense you must assume $T$ is one-to-one, otherwise a nonzero vector in the kernel loses the well-definedness of its angle after applying $T$.

Comment: So, yeah, what @Brian Fitzpatrick just said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x \in \ker(T)$ and $y \notin \ker(T)$.

Then, $T(y) = T(x+y)$, and the angle between the images becomes $0$, while the angle between $y$ and $x+y$ is arbitrary.

Comment: nice; this is much transparent. But, if $T=0$, you will not have choice of $y$; how do we contradict?

Answer (score 0):

According to your definition, only the angle between two non-zero vectors make sense, and any two non-zero vectors have a well defined angle between them. So any linear transformation $T$ that maps a non-zero vector $x_0$ into zero cannot preserve the angle, because then the angle between $x_0$ and any other non-zero vector $y$ will not be preserved, as the angle between $Tx_0=0$ and $Ty$ will not make sense anymore. This means, the only vector mapped by $T$ to zero has to be the vector zero. In other words $T$ is invertible (it has rank $n$).